# Should "pronunciation" be added as one of the tags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

I'm new to the German branch of StackExchange, but I asked a question about pronunciation of a certain sound/letter, and surprisingly couldn't find a tag for "pronunciation", so I had to tag it "letter".

I don't have enough reputation to add tags yet, but do you guys think it's reasonable to have that tag? If so, can someone do it, please, because I think I might one day ask another question like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you you brought this up. Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce this here. We do have the tag [pronunciation](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation) for quite a while now with up to day already 71 questions tagged with it. For now I added the tag to your question.

To add a tag we can choose from exisiting tags that pop up as soon as we start typing. Choose the appropriate tag or auto-complete it with <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Oh, I wonder why it didn't work for me before... :/
Oh well, thanks for your help!

Comment: yeah weird - you may have had a typo or something.